# Python: Column with icons, how to read each icon then categorize them in order?

Tags: python, image, list, categorization

So there's a column of items...

[image]

Let's say it looks like this:

X Item 1
C Item 2
J Item 3
K Item 4
X Item 5
X Item 6

Where X, C, J, and K, are image icons. This is on a web browser.

I want to be able to read each item that show up on the screen, and place them in a list, in descending order, so the icons would be read, then placed in a list that looked like this: [X, C, J, K, X, X]

I know ways you can find X icon, so you can do pyautogui.locateOnScreen('X.png'), and it would find the coordinates of X. You can also do pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('X.png') and this would find the coordinates of ALL X instances...

These are images that have to be read. How do you read each icon, in yrange, and categorize them?

So basically turn:
X Item 1
C Item 2
J Item 3
K Item 4
X Item 5
X Item 6

Into: [X, C, J, K, X, X]

(remember icon images!!)

Comment: _"(I took a screenshot but it won't let me post it due to less than 10 rep)"_. Put it on imgur and post a link.

Comment: Here you go: http://i.imgur.com/UgTNHvL.png

Comment: Is this on a html page? If so than you are looking for how to scrape a page with something like BeautifulSoup

Comment: It _is_ in HTML, but reading through it, a lot of it was generated by either javascript or ruby, it doesn't even look like html at all... Let's say it was flash, how would you read the screen?